# Why does ArcGIS Desktop 10 HTML popups give JavaScript/HTML Error?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, javascript, popup, html, arcgis-desktop

Using ArcMap 10 Desktop HTML Popups.

The issue I am having is that the html < select > elements aren't working - you can select it and use the arrow keys to navigate through(up/down) the list but you can't bring up a drop down with the visible list bit.

When on desktop IE running in ie 7 or 8 mode selects don't work I get a popup notification but it wont allow me to unblock it.

This a bug, is there a fix? can I upgrade the IE higher than 7/8? chromeframe? I just need to get the selects working.

```
< ? php

#$tmp = "< select id='something' >";

for(something){

$value = "value";

$name = "name"; 

#$tmp.="< option value="$value" >$name< / option >";    

    }       

#$tmp.="< /select>";

echo $tmp;

? >
```

Comment: When and how are the popups triggered, and what is their purpose?

Comment: Popup is pointed to a url and there is some processing based on get variables it passes. the select is dynamic and is given values based on what is passed through the url.

Comment: <br>In arc map you click on an item.

<br>The popup open sends one of the id fields from the table as a get variable

<br>The select is there for the user to pick an action from a list of actions

<br>I can see the select, I can move through the list but when i click on it, the dropdown list is not displayed only the current item and to switch between them I gotta use the up and down arrows.

<br>I need to display those values as a dropdown, so the user knows what other actions they can perform without having to scroll through the list on their keyboard.

Comment: Couldn't duplicate the error on winxp arcMap 9.x or win 7 arcMap 10
Only on my machine xp arcMap 10.

Comment: I know this isn't real helpful, but I didn't even know you could put Javascript into an HTML popup inside ArcGIS desktop. That seems like using the function for something it wasn't intended. Wouldn't it be better to host the HTML/javascript on a web page (perhaps an aspx or jsp) where you can pass your parameters, like your variable(s), and then host the javascript on that page?

Answer (score 1):

My reading of your Question says that you are/were seeing this problem on Internet Explorer (mode) 7 and 8 but only on one Windows XP machine running ArcGIS Desktop 10.0.

It was not reproducible for you using ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 on Windows 7 or ArcGIS Desktop 9.3 on Windows XP.

Internet Explorer 7 and 8 are still listed under the [System Requirements of ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.2/index.html#//015100000002000000) so if the problem persists for you at the latest version then I recommend that you contact your local [Esri Support](http://support.esri.com/en/).